# ASM- LC3 Troubleshooting Problem Not Printing R0 Correctly

Tags: assembly, lc3

I have a intro ASM problem.
Problem: Multiply 4 x 3 and print the result
I have the loop putting the correct answer in the registry, but when i use "OUT" after the loop it prints □. Would like it to print "12" CODE is below.

```
LD R0, reset
LD R1, reset
ADD R0, R0, #0  ;set R1 to zero
LD R2, number1
LD R3, number2





; enter loop
MULTIPLY 
ADD R0, R0, R2 ; add to sum

ADD R3, R3, #-1 ; decrement our counter

BRp MULTIPLY ; continue until the 2nd num is 0


OUT

number1 .FILL 4
number2 .FILL 3

reset .Fill #0
```

Answer (score 0):

The `OUT` trap instruction prints a single character, from its ASCII code.  In LC-3, there is no trap instruction to print numbers directly — only ASCII characters can be printed.

If you want to print a number in decimal you have to write code to do that by printing the ASCII character for `1`, which is 48 and then print the ASCII character for `2`, which is 49.

If you know some value is only one decimal digit long, you can add 48 to it and that will print a value between 0 and 9.

However, if the value is larger than 9, LC-3 will not automatically print extra digits (`OUT` will print one ASCII character, e.g. for 10 the above will print `:` because 10+48=58, which is the ASCII code for `:`), so you need a small algorithm for printing multiple digits.

Let's say we want to be able to print up to 2 digits.  Then check if the number is > 9 (or >= 10), and if so, then divide the number by 10 and print the character for that digit, followed by the character for the remainder.  (If you don't do the check, and go right for the divide by 10, that algorithm will print a leading zero for numbers less than 10.)

A general purpose algorithm to convert a number into a string of digits (e.g. for printing) can be searched for using the term `itoa`, which stands for integer-to-ascii.  (The reverse algorithm, ascii-to-integer, used for reading user input strings into numbers, can be searched for using `atoi`.)

Further, just like you are doing multiply by successive addition, on LC-3, we can do division by successive subtraction.